# SP Online generate refresh token for testing REST api calls in Postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

I'm refining SPO API calls intended for a mobile app project using Postman, and all is fine except the access token keeps expiring after maybe a day.

How do I get the "refresh token" to work so I don't have to generate a new token each day?

I tried adding `enable_auto_refresh_access_token = true` in the token POST call, but I've no idea if that's what's required.

Update:
Post call:

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/xxxxx/tokens/OAuth/2
```

The only header setting in the post is "content-type" application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Header values in response:

[image]

Comment: HI Can you please show a screenshot of your post header parameters. And can you confirm you are getting a refresh token back. The idea is that you can store the refresh token in a variable for later re-use.

Comment: @JamesRandal I updated the question. Not seeing a refresh token in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The above requests you're using should be [client credentials flow](https://www.anexinet.com/blog/getting-an-access-token-for-sharepoint-online/)

[image]

This flow [won't expose a refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3). By the way even if it offers a refresh token, you need to send request to refresh the access token each day as refresh token cannot be used to access the API directly, this won't save anything.

BR

Comment: That's why I'm asking - how do I get a refresh token? Msft documentation I've seen doesn't cover this.